# Split paragraphs into sentences - a special case

Tags: java

I am a newbie to programming in Java. I want to split the paragraphs in one file into sentences and write them in a different file. Also there should be mechanism to identify which sentence comes from which paragraph.The code I have used so far is mentioned below. But this code breaks:

```
Former Secretary of Finance Dr. P.B. Jayasundera is being questioned by the police Financial Crime Investigation Division.
```

into

```
Former Secretary of Finance Dr.
P.B.
Jayasundera is being questioned by the police Financial Crime Investigation Division.
```

How can I correct it? Thanks in advance.

```
import java.io.*;  
class trial4{  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException   
 {  
 FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");  
 BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);  
 String s;  
 OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("output10.txt");  
                      String token[];  

 while((s = br.readLine()) != null)  
    {  
      token = s.split("(?<=[.!?])\\s* ");
      for(int i=0;i<token.length;i++)  
       {  
         byte buf[]=token[i].getBytes(); 
     for(int j=0;j<buf.length;j=j+1)  
         {  
                                out.write(buf[j]);  
                 if(j==buf.length-1)  
                        out.write('\n');  
            }  
         }  
      }  
       fr.close();  
  }  
}
```

I referenced all the similar questions posted on StackOverFlow. But those answers couldn't help me solve this.

Comment: This will be reasonably hard to do unless you can formalize some notion of "this period marks an abbreviation" vs "this period marks the end of a sentence".

Answer (score 0):

How about using a negative-lookbehind in conjunction with a replace. Simply said: Replace all line endings that don't have "something special" before them with the line end followed by newline.

A list of "known abbreviations" will be needed. There's no guarantee as to how long those can be or how short a word at the end of a line might be. (See? 'be' if quite short already!)

```
class trial4{  
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {  
     FileReader fr = new FileReader("input.txt");  
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);  
     PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("output10.txt")); 

     String s = br.readLine();
     while(s != null) {  
        out.print(        //Prints newline after each line in any case
           s.replaceAll("(?i)"             //Make the match case insensitive
                 + "(?<!"                  //Negative lookbehind
                 +   "(\\W\\w)|"           //Single non-word followed by word character (P.B.)
                 +   "(\\W\\d{1,2})|"      //one or two digits (dates!)
                 +   "(\\W(dr|mr|mrs|ms))" //List of known abbreviations
                 + ")"                     //End of lookbehind                     
                 +"([!?\\.])"              //Match end-ofsentence
                    , "$5"                 //Replace with end-of-sentence found
                          +System.lineSeparator())); //Add newline if found
       s = br.readLine();
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes! :). And I have another question. What if these paragraphs are in an Excel sheet? Let's say one cell contains one paragraph. After splitting them, the sentences could be in a text file/Excel sheet. (Either way). So then, how this can be achieved?

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry to bother again. But when I give values like 3.2, it breaks into different sentences now. I didn't have this issue before.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment "it will be reasonable hard" to break text into paragraphs without formalizing the requirements. Take a look at BreakIterator  - especially SentenceInstance. You might roll out your own BreakIterator since it breaks the same as you get with regexp, except that it is more abstract. Or try to find a 3rd party solution like http://deeplearning4j.org/sentenceiterator.html which can be **trained to tokenize your input**.

Example with BreakIterator:

```
String str = "Former Secretary of Finance Dr. P.B. Jayasundera is being questioned by the police Financial Crime Investigation Division.";

BreakIterator bilus = BreakIterator.getSentenceInstance(Locale.US); 
bilus.setText(str);

int last  = bilus.first();
int count = 0;

while (BreakIterator.DONE != last)
{
    int first = last;       
    last = bilus.next();

    if (BreakIterator.DONE != last)
    {
        String sentence = str.substring(first, last);
        System.out.println("Sentence:" + sentence);
        count++;
    }
}
System.out.println("" + count + " sentences found.");
```